# Chebysheff $\psi$ and 'music of primes'

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have seen in a lecture the following identity for the [Chebysheff $\psi$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function):
$$\psi(x) = x-\log(2\pi)\; - \sum_{\zeta(\rho)=0}\frac{x^\rho}{\rho} \\
          = x-\log(2\pi)\; - \frac{1}{2}\log(1-\frac{1}{x^2}) \\ 
            -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{|\rho_k|}x^{\Re(\rho_k)}\cos[\Im(\rho_k)\log(x)-\arg(\rho_k)] $$

The first identity is famous and I can find derivations of that, also the log expression for the trivial zeros ($\frac{1}{2}\log(1-\frac{1}{x^2})$) is clear to me. I cannot understand where the one for the non-trivial zeros $\rho_k$ comes from. The expression is mentioned also in the context of the "music of primes" for more or less obvious reasons. Can someone explain if this expression is correct and how to derive it?

Comment: Sorry I think I got it. $x^\rho = x^{\Re(\rho)} \exp(i \log x \Im(\rho))$ ..

Comment: A non-trivial zero $\rho$ comes in pair with its complex conjugate $\overline{\rho}$, equivalently $\psi(x)$ is real.. What is non-trivial is that $\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} $ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group two conjugate nontrivial zeros, say $\rho_k = \sigma_k + i t_k$ with $t_k > 0$ and write $\rho_k = \lvert\rho_k\rvert e^{i \alpha_k}$. Then

\begin{align}
\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k} + \frac{x^{\overline{\rho_k}}}{\overline{\rho_k}} &= \frac{x^{\sigma_k}}{\lvert \rho_k\rvert}\bigl(x^{it_k}e^{-i\alpha_k} + x^{-it_k}e^{i\alpha_k}\bigr) \\
&= \frac{x^{\sigma_k}}{\lvert \rho_k\rvert}\cdot 2\Re \bigl(x^{it_k}e^{-i\alpha_k}\bigr) \tag{$z + \overline{z} = 2\Re z$}\\
&= 2\frac{x^{\sigma_k}}{\lvert \rho_k\rvert}\cdot \Re e^{it_k\log x - i\alpha_k} \tag{$x^w = e^{w\log x}$}\\
&= 2\frac{x^{\sigma_k}}{\lvert \rho_k\rvert}\cdot \cos \bigl(t_k\log x - \alpha_k\bigr) \tag{$\Re e^{iy} = \cos y$}\\
&= \frac{2}{\lvert\rho_k\rvert} x^{\Re \rho_k}\cos \bigl(\Im \rho_k(\log x) - \operatorname{arg} \rho_k\bigr).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for making all steps very explicit!